# QGIS: Snap geometries to layer - not all points are snapping

Tags: qgis, snapping

I am trying to snap sample collection points to the nearest location on a path, however, not all points are snapping correctly.

I use the tool `snap geometries to layer` and choose the option `prefer closest point, don't insert new vertices` to get snapped points that are now somewhere along the path. I set the tolerance limit to 100 metres.

The output shows some points are correctly snapping, but there are many which do not, despite being within the tolerance limit. And in one case, a point is snapping not to the nearest point on the path, but to the end of it.

I am unsure why this is happening as all the settings seem to be correct to my knowledge. Below is an example of part of the output. The white circle is the original position while grey/blue is the snapped output. I've added a line between unsnapped and snapped points so that it is easier to see how the points have snapped. You can see on the right that there are many which have not been snapped even though that distance ranges from 30m to 50m. On the left, there is that point that did not snap to the closest point on the path.

[image]

I am working on QGIS version 3.30. Both layers have the same CRS (EPSG:32749 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 49S), and all points are well within 100 metres to a path.

Any ideas? I've also tried `prefer closest point, insert new vertices where required` but the output is exactly the same as the image above.

Comment: It looks like the lines are composed of few vertices (i.e. start & end) and not many along the straight part of the line itself. Try running with 'Prefer closest point, insert extra vertices where required'.

Comment: Other option: use Geometry by expression with `overlay_nearest()` and `closest_point()` functions

Comment: @Cushen I tried this as well but no luck - the output is exactly the same as the image I've provided. (I've now included this information in the original post)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Babel. I'm unfamiliar with how to use function in QGIS with what you've provided. Could you please offer some more clarity as to how to incorporate those functions in the geometry expression box? Keeping in mind the the points and line layer are two independent layers. Thanks

Comment: You might make a copy of your lines layers, then densify it to add regular vertices, and then run the snap tool on your points.  Or/and you might also enable snapping and in the snapping settings try some different ones.